# How do I generate the equivalent of a dynamic block connector in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio, vector-graphics, flowchart

Visio has the useful 'Connector' tool which snaps nicely, makes right angles, and is conveniently adjustable. But - it only produces a line connection, not a block, like with the simpler block connectors. How can I (easily) produce **block** connectors with more than one angle? Bonus points for referring to curves as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the line width to whatever size you want, 32pt makes a nice thick block. To make it curve just **right-click** and select **Curved connector**.

Comment: No, that won't do it, since I need both a fill color (and pattern or gradient) and a line color. And dashing, possibly.